# How to control which order Winamp plays the playlist?

Tags: winamp, playlists

I created a long playlist, then sorted it by filename, now when i press next button to play next track, it doesnt play the next track in the playlist, but something totally random in that list.

How do i tell Winamp which order it will play the tracks? For example, i would like to first randomize the list, and then start playing from top to bottom, so i can continue the next day from where i left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must turn off the **Shuffle** option in Winamp to play tracks in order.

[image]

Comment: @Tom Wijsman: Thanks for adding the screenshot. I didn't add one since I don't know which version (or skin) the questioner is using.

Comment: The `/review/low-quality-posts` tab made me do it, and I give a free up vote along... :)